# Accessing UI elements in Activity from another class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with that code

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
text.setText("Hello Android");
```

It works if it's inside an activity, but if it isn't, obviously, it gives errors:

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type new TimerTask(){}
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type new TimerTask(){}
```

The code is inside a timer in separate class (not activity). The full code is as follows.

```
//main timer task for ingame time processing
static Timer gameTimer = new Timer();
static TimerTask gameTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
        text.setText("Hello Android");
    }
};
```

I tried changing it like that

```
ScreenGame.this.setContentView(R.layout.game);
TextView text = (TextView) ScreenGame.this.findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
text.setText("Hello Android");
```

But it still doesn't work :(

*PS - Yes, I searched other similar questions, but all of them although appear to be the same, in fact completely different.*

Comment: You want to use a callback to the UI thread instead of trying to change it from another thread (which isn't allowed). Check out [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScreenGame.this.setContentView(R.layout.game);
TextView text = (TextView) ScreenGame.this.findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
text.setText("Hello Android");
```

is exactly the same as

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
text.setText("Hello Android");
```

---

**wrong code**

<sub>You should make a parent class, that fires off all the other Activities. In that parent class, you can have a reference to each child activity, and you can ask each child for it's textfield:</sub>

```
// In the parent:
child.getTextView().setText("Hello galaxy!");

// with the child method:
TextView getTextView () {
  return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
}
```

---

EDIT: More info:

The code I gave was not good, I hadn't understood your problem well... I hope I do now, do I'll try to correct myself.

Make a seperate class, for example `MyTimer`, which will extends the `TimerTask` class:

```
class MyTimer extends TimerTask {
  // your class
}
```

Make a constructor, that excepts an TextView as an argument, and saves a reference to it.

```
TextView theTextView;
MyTimer (TextView tv) {
  this.theTextView = tv;
}
```

Now implement `run()`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    thetextView.setText("Hello Galaxy!");
}
```

Call make this class using the following code:

```
static TimerTask gameTimerTask = new MyTimer((TextView) findViewById(R.id.qwe_string));
```

I hope this is all correct, I have to do this from memory as I don't have any testing environment. At least it should help you in the right direction.

Comment: Hm. Can you please elaborate on what I should do and how it should look? Because I'm not entirely sure I understand how you say to do it.

Comment: What part? The parent of the child Activity?

Comment: Yes, the whole deal with the parent class, please. Because I can't understand how to do it for android considering how android programming is a little bit different from usual...

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

```
ScreenGame.this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
   TextView text = (TextView) ScreenGame.this.findViewById(R.id.qwe_string);
   text.setText("Hello Android");  }
 });
```

And you should call the following line in `onCreate()` of `ScreenGame`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

Comment: I do call setContentView(R.layout.game); on onCreate. And if you read the whole post you would see that I do exactly that. I added ScreenGame.this. but it doesn't work regardless.

Comment: Read my post again please. You will see that there are more differences than adding ScreenGame.this here.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But it doesn't work as I said... (I should have been more clear when I replied, you are right). Anyway, it just gives an error: No enclosing instance of the type ScreenGame is accessible in scope.

Comment: Can you try again by removing `static` in front of `TimerTask` definition.

Comment: But then you cannot access the activity instance. If static is completely necessary, you should consider extending TimerTask and adding a method like setMyActivity() so that you can pass an instance of your activity for later calling findViewById() on it.